# get sim serial number in codename one using android native code

Tags: android, codenameone

I want to get `sim serial number` in codename one using Android native code, following is my native implementation class, I have also **added permission** in build hint, code doesn't give any error but return `null`

```
    import com.codename1.impl.android.AndroidNativeUtil;
    import android.telephony.TelephonyManager;

    public class MyNativeImpl {

            public String simID() {
            TelephonyManager tMgr=(TelephonyManager) AndroidNativeUtil.getActivity().getSystemService("phone");        
            String SIMSerialNumber=tMgr.getSimSerialNumber();  
                 return SIMSerialNumber;
            }

             public boolean isSupported() {
                return true;
            }
    }
```

I have added this code,

`if(!AndroidNativeUtil.checkForPermission(Manifest.permission‌​.READ_PHONE_STATE, "This should be the description shown to the user...")){ your code here }`

but getting error like

> error: package Manifest does not exist
>                 if(!AndroidNativeUtil.checkForPermission(Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE,
>   "App requires the permission to work properly"))
>                                                                  ^ Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API. Note: Recompile
>   with -Xlint:deprecation for details. Note: Some input files use
>   unchecked or unsafe operations. Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked
>   for details. 1 error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a [library](https://github.com/Pmovil/Telephony) written by Fabricio Cabeca a while ago for that.

Search the Codename Extensions Library for Telephony (Right-click project -> Codename One -> CodenameOne Settings -> Extensions). Use this cn1LIb.

If there's still an issue with Android below 6.0,

add `android.xpermissions=<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>` to your build hint.

And also make sure you're not testing on Dual sim device as this could problematic.

Comment: could you explain a little bit more about using cn1Llb. I have read this already

Comment: I have added this extension

Comment: If you want to divide your work to an external group. For this purpose use the cn1lib approach.
You can say it Modularity.

Comment: You can refer to this answer for that : https://stackoverflow.com/a/34628176/7652758

Comment: The answer is correct but you neglected to ask for phone permissions in your code for Android 6+ so it will fail on the newer devices. See https://www.codenameone.com/manual/advanced-topics.html You need to wrap the call with `if(!AndroidNativeUtil.checkForPermission(Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE, "This should be the description shown to the user...")){ your code here }`

Comment: @ShaiAlmog do I need to get runtime permissions here? if yes how to do it?it?

Answer (score 0):

I think sim serial Number and sim number is unique. You can try this for get sim serial number and get sim number and Don't forget to add permission in manifest file.

```
TelephonyManager telemamanger = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
String getSimSerialNumber = telemamanger.getSimSerialNumber();
String getSimNumber = telemamanger.getLine1Number();
```

And add below permission into your `Androidmanifest.xml` file.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
```

Comment: please refer this example hope so it will be helpful for you https://github.com/Pmovil/Telephony

Comment: I checked the link but Telephony does not have any method for serial number